# matrix multiplication in swift using Accelerate framework 32 bit vs 64 bit

Tags: ios, swift, 32bit-64bit, accelerate-framework

I am trying to do matrix multiplication in Swift using the Accelerate framework. Used the vDSP_mmulD. This worked perfectly in the iPhone6 , 6 plus, iPad Air simulator (all 64 bit architecture) but did not work with any of the 32 bit architecture devices.
It sees like vDSP_mmulD is not recognized by the 32 bit architecture and the program does not build. Error message displayed is "use of unresolved identifier 'vDSP_mmulD'" Has anybody else seen this error? Please let me know your thoughts. I am using Xcode 6.1.
Thanks.

Comment: Haven't used Accelerate framework, but IMO you should rethink before spending too much efforts on 32 bits. Apple is asking developers to focus on 64 bit. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a

Comment: @chunkyguy they are encouraging 64bit builds to avoid loading 32bit libraries on 64bit devices. However, 32bit devices are still around and writing code compatible with various architectures is recommended.

Comment: If you copy/pasted that error message, your problem is that you transposed a couple letters at the beginning of vSDP_mmulD.

Comment: @NateCook. That was a typo on my part. On 64 bit it runs fine but on 32 bit devices the program will not build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution: use `cblas_dgemm` instead (also part of Accelerate).  It's at least as fast as `vDSP_mmulD` on all systems, and much faster on some (in iOS 8 and Yosemite, `vDSP_mmulD` is actually just a wrapper around `cblas_dgemm`), and it should actually work here.

I suspect that your build is failing for the 32-bit simulator; on i386, vDSP_mmulD is actually a macro around mmulD, and Swift does not fully support C language macros.

Note: I have a suspicion that you may be working with 3x3 or 4x4 matrices, in which case none of the Accelerate routines are really what you want (they're aimed a larger matrices); you want inline vector sequences like the ones defined in `<simd/matrix.h>`.  Unfortunately, Swift doesn't support SIMD vectors, so that's not an option.  Your best bet at this point may be to simply write out the elementwise computation, and report a bug to request that Swift support the `<simd/simd.h>` interfaces.

Comment: You sound more like you know what you're talking about :)

Comment: I multiplying 1x9 , 9x1 matrices. Thanks for the tip. I will try the cblas_dgemm.

Comment: Tried the easy way out (element wise computation). The program slowed down drastically. I need to perform 1620 [1x9]x[9x1] matrix multiplication to get a result. I guess this is only possible using the cblas_dgemm for now. I am looking online but did not find a lot of help on this. I will continue to work on this to make it work. For now the error I get when I use the cblas_gemm is 'Cannot invoke 'subscript' with an augment list...' Please let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks.

Comment: 1x9x9x1 is really a dot product.  You will likely find it easier to use cblas_ddot.

Comment: In the interests of providing a more efficient solution, are you multiplying one vector by 1620 other vectors?  Each of 20 vectors by each of 81 vectors?  How are they arranged in memory?

Comment: I have a matrix A of size [18x18]. I need to square this matrix. The result needs to be squared again. This happens 5 times therefore, I need A power 32. I could not find a command to do this, so I am computing the dot product of each row and column 1680 (18x18x5) times to get the result I need. So if there exists a command A power n, the computations speed can further improve.

Comment: There's no A**n for matrices in Accelerate, but should be able to call `cblas_dgemm` five times.  This should be significantly more efficient.  I'll see if I can provide you with some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

So this is all speculative, since I don't have a 32-bit device to test with right now, and I can't find any documentation to support this, but perhaps Accelerate works with different floating-point types on the two different architectures - `Float` on a 32-bit architecture and `Double` on a 64-bit architecture. The `D` at the end of `vDSP_mmulD` stands for `Double`, so you'd need to be able to use the `Float` version on 32-bit architecture in your code: `vDSP_mmul`.

You can use an `#if...#else...#endif` preprocessing block to toggle which methods you're using (info at the [bottom of this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)). One trick to get around Swift's strict static typing would be to put something like this preprocessing block at the top of your file:

```
#if arch(x86_64) || arch(arm64)
    typealias M_Float = Double
    let M_vDSP_mmul = vDSP_mmulD
    // add Double versions of other Accelerate functions you need
#else
    typealias M_Float = Float
    let M_vDSP_mmul = vDSP_mmul
    // add Float versions of other Accelerate functions you need
#endif
```

Then instead of having to pick whether you're working with `Float` or `Double`, or which method to use all throughout your code, you could just use `M_Float` and your `M_...` versions of the Accelerate functions:

```
var number: M_Float = 0    // Double on 64-bit, Float on 32-bit
M_vDSP_mmul(...)           // correct version either way
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found this [collections library](https://github.com/mauriciosantos/Buckets-Swift/) for swift. It provides a matrix struct with multiplication operators using Accelerate. Worked for me.