# cblas_dgemm issues in Swift using Accelerate Framework

Tags: swift, xcode6, matrix-multiplication, accelerate-framework

I wanted to multiply two matrices in Swift. I found a great reply in this thread : [matrix multiplication in swift using Accelerate framework 32 bit vs 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519169/matrix-multiplication-in-swift-using-accelerate-framework-32-bit-vs-64-bit) in which I am told to use cblas_dgemm to multiply two matrices.
Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import Accelerate


class GetMatrix {
var cols:Int, rows:Int
var matrix:[Double]


init(cols:Int, rows:Int) {
    self.cols = cols
    self.rows = rows
    matrix = Array(count:cols*rows, repeatedValue:0.0)
}

subscript(col:Int, row:Int) -> Double {
    get {
        return matrix[cols * row + col]
    }
    set {
        matrix[cols*row+col] = newValue
    }
}

func colCount() -> Int {
    return self.cols
}

func rowCount() -> Int {
    return self.rows
}
}
class GameScene: SKScene {


var firstMatrix = GetMatrix(cols: 18, rows: 18)
var secondMatrix = GetMatrix(cols: 18, rows: 18)
var answerMatrix = GetMatrix(cols: 18, rows: 18)


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    for c in 0...17 {
        for r in 0...17 {
            firstMatrix[r,c] = 2.0
        }
    }
    for c in 0...17 {
        for r in 0...17 {
            secondMatrix[r,c] = 1.0
        }
    }
    for c in 0...17 {
        for r in 0...17 {
            answerMatrix[r,c] = 0.0
        }
    }


    cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 18, 18, 18, 1.0, firstMatrix, 18, secondMatrix, 18, 0.0, answerMatrix, 18) // Error in this line



}


}
```

The code does not build. The line with cblas_dgemm has the issue. It says "GetMatrix' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer' Please help, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var firstMatrix = GetMatrix(cols: 18, rows: 18)
var secondMatrix = GetMatrix(cols: 18, rows: 18)
var answerMatrix = GetMatrix(cols: 18, rows: 18)
.
.
.
cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 18, 18, 18, 1.0, firstMatrix, 18, secondMatrix, 18, 0.0, answerMatrix, 18)
```

Your code passes the class GetMatrix to the cblas_dgemm. You will have to pass reference to the actual matrix. Something like

```
cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 18, 18, 18, 1.0, &firstMatrix.matrix, 18, &secondMatrix.matrix, 18, 0.0, &answerMatrix.matrix, 18)
```

(provided that the other parameters are correct)